# msg seviri l1.5 native files

Tags: python-3.x, satpy

I am trying to use satpy to read native file from Eumetsat. However, I am getting errors when trying to read my file even after reading from multiple sources and using examples.
the file is stored in this directory; C:/Users/nk22017786/Desktop/satellite/MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190615165742.199000000Z-NA

## Date format in YYYYMMDDhhmm

```
fnames = glob('C:/Users/nk22017786/Desktop/satellite/MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190615165742.199000000Z-NA.nat')
scn =  Scene(filenames=[fnames], reader="seviri_l1b_native", reader_kwargs={'fill_disk': True})
scn.load(['VIS006'], upper_right_corner='NE')
print(scn['VIS006'])type here
```

I tried this too;

```
filenames = ['MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190313151244.440000000Z-NA.nat']
global_scene = Scene(reader='seviri_l1b_native', filenames=[filenames])
global_scene.load(['VIS006'])
type here
```

error;AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

tried this again

```
filenames = ['MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190313151244.440000000Z-NA']
scn = Scene(filenames=filenames, reader='seviri_l1b_native')
scn.load(['VIS006', 'IR_108'], upper_right_corner='NE')
print(scn['IR_108']type here
```

error;No filenames found for reader: seviri_l1b_native
Don't know how to open the following files: {'MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190313151244.440000000Z-NA'}

Comment: In your first two code blocks you are passing filenames as a list of a list `[[my_file.nat]]` instead of a single list. In the last case it looks like your filenames are recognized by Satpy. I'll ask on the pytroll slack to see if some of the EUMETSAT folks know where these filenames are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, in the two first examples you are passing a list of list of files, which satpy doesn't like.

The last snippet should work if you provide the extension of the file also, as in:

```
filenames = ['MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20190313151244.440000000Z-NA.nat']
scn = Scene(filenames=filenames, reader='seviri_l1b_native')
scn.load(['VIS006', 'IR_108'], upper_right_corner='NE')
```